# Discord bot C# reading specific messgaes on the requested channel

Tags: c#, bots, discord

So I've started building a discord bot with c#; a murder game where the person A types '?kill' and then it would 'kill' the person right above the sent cmd message. Here is where I run into a problem; I can't seem to find the code that can scan/read the user ID of the message above the author's message. Unlike the popular purge/erase command, which you can delete x numbers of messages, I need the bot to specificly 'select' a specific message. Anyone got any clues?

Here is an example situation:

Person B: bla bla bla

Person A(murderer): ?kill

(Bot scans/finds the authur of the message above the cmd.)

Bot: Person A has killed Person B!

Comment: What platform or framework are you building this bot in?

Comment: I'm building this on windows visual studio 2019, with console application. Net framework, with the d#(discord bot stuff)

Comment: By `D#` do you mean `DiscordSharp` ?

Comment: Yep, plus, interactivity and commandsnext

Answer (score 0):

First of all since you've mentioned that you are using DiscordSharp, I 'll personally recommend that you use `Discord.Net` as the D# library **hasn't been updated for a couple of years now** and `Discord.Net` is in continuous development and has a dozen of APIs to connect to Discord Bot API.

Although you can connect to the API from other online services like `LUIS`, `DialogFlow` and frameworks like `Oscova` I'll pen down a code for direct interaction via `Discord.Net`.

In Visual Studio:

- Select `Tools`
- Choose `NuGet Package Manager` and select `Package Manager Console`

Enter the following command (after you've removed the current D# package)

`Install-Package Discord.Net`

You can get the user ID and send a message to the right channel/user via the `SocketMessage` object that is received in the `Client.MessageReceived` event.

```cs
Client = new DiscordSocketClient();
Client.MessageReceived += ClientOnMessageReceived;

await Client.LoginAsync(TokenType.Bot, "YOUR_BOT_TOKEN");
await Client.StartAsync();
```

Create some event handler. In the code below you can see how to fetch a couple of user and activity information.

```cs
private async Task ClientOnMessageReceived(SocketMessage socketMessage)
{
    await Task.Run(() =>
    {
        //Activity is not from a Bot.
        if (!socketMessage.Author.IsBot)
        {

            var authorId = socketMessage.Author.Id;
            var channelId  = socketMessage.Channel.Id.ToString();
            var messageId = socketMessage.Id.ToString();
            var message = socketMessage.Content;

            var channel = Client.GetChannel(Convert.ToUInt64(channelId));
            var socketChannel = (ISocketMessageChannel)channel;

            //Do Something and send a response here.
            socketChannel.SendMessageAsync("YOUR RESPONSE");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Hello. Thanks for spending some of your time on helping me out! Though I think I have 1 thing to clarify: won't doing this scan the author that made the command? Or should I rather first erase the command text first, so that the 'latest' message will be the other person's?

Comment: The one who sends you the message is the one who should receive it. Channel IDs can help you in your case.